# PHP: is there an easy way to modifiy a string via splitting them every N symbols?

Tags: php, string, split

For example, i have

```
string=abcdefgh
```

and N=3, `delimiter=*`,

i need to have

```
newstring=abc*def*gh
```

I can't find a function to do this.

Comment: `echo implode("*", str_split("abcdefgh", 3));`

Comment: @RiggsFolly: What was wrong with _modificate_ ?

Comment: Works fine! Thanks. I forgot, that string is array of symbols.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: That was a joke... :-(

Comment: @AbraCadaver Sorry squire, didnt see that :) ... :)

Comment: @WallOfBytes _Just for reference_ That answer has nothing to do with a string being an array

Answer (score 1):

You could use [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). Then, you could write:

```
function special_split($str, $n, $delimiter='*') {
    $strs = str_split($str, $n);
    return implode($delimiter, $strs);
}
```

Usage:

```
echo special_split("abcdefgh", 3); //abc*def*gh
```